# Stopping Excel Conditional Formatting rules changing between tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting, rules

So I have set up a worksheet for my job and it is spread out between 3 different excel tabs. I created a number of different Conditional Formatting Rules to set up all the sheets in the same way to have specific colors in certain circumstances.

I am having troubles where when I copy/paste a line from one tab to another that it will duplicate the conditional formatting rules and change around the affected area for all the rules on the sheet as well (for some reason not everytime) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGPdY.png)insert some mumbo jumbo into the formula itself basically ruining the rule and I have to keep re-correcting the rules.

Has anybody found a way to stop excel from copying the rules over through the lines without having to just straight up retype the information?

Looking for help if anyone has anything they noticed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paste Special in the home tab.
[image]